# Render Hosted Postgres database throws ECONNRESET on any connection attempt Node Express App

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, econnreset, render.com

I am unable to query my Postgres DB in Render. I researched this issue online and found that it was a common problem but none of the solutions I found worked.

Here is my server-side code (I am using NodeJS, Express, Typescript and Postgres)

```
import postgres, { RowList, Row } from 'postgres'
import appconfig from '../app.config'

type Query = (sql: string) => Promise<RowList<Row[]>>

const query: Query = async (sql) => {
  try {
    const q = postgres({
      host: appconfig.database.host,
      port: appconfig.database.port,
      database: appconfig.database.schema,
      username: appconfig.database.username,
      password: appconfig.database.password,
    })
    const res = await q`${sql}`

    return res
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
  }
}

export default query
```

I receive the following error every time and have not had a successful attempt. It's worth noting I have no issues connecting from PGAdmin on the same PC with the same credentials

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)      
    at cachedError (C:\Users\xxxxx\repos\one-watch\node_modules\postgres\cjs\src\query.js:171:23)
    at new Query (C:\Users\xxxxx\repos\one-watch\node_modules\postgres\cjs\src\query.js:36:24)
    at sql (C:\Users\xxxxx\repos\one-watch\node_modules\postgres\cjs\src\index.js:111:11)
    at C:\Users\xxxxx\repos\one-watch\src\database\query.ts:15:24
```

I have never used postgres before, all of my database experience has been in mysql up to this point, although I don't expect this is a postgres problem but potentially just a nuance of Render's implementation of their Postgres service. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

The only articles I've found like [this one](https://community.render.com/t/econnreset-with-node-js-and-postgresql/1498) are related but they are able to get at least some sort of successful connection at least once. In my case they are all failing.

Answer (score 7):

Adding

> ?sslmode=no-verify

in the end of the url worked for me.